# Send 2D Array to JTable

Tags: java, swing

I am using swing and java in Eclipse to send data to JTable from a 2D Array
    String [][] row = {{"iphone"},{"34567"}};
I have a 2D array. I am wanting to display it in JTable using eclipse. 
The JTable will have to header like "Phone" and "Price" and the Jtable gets filled by the click of a button.

```
String[] columns = {"Phone","Price"};
```

Can some please help me to get it displayed in JTable

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to the question can best be found by reading through [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and the associated examples which show clearly the solutions to the question within the first section - [Creating a simple table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Column1", "Column2"})
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

To add a row:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

model.addRow(new Object[]{"iPhone", "73567",});
```

Placing the above code inside the action performed of the button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel(); 

    model.addRow(new Object[]{"iphone", "73576"});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination but i am getting error on your 1st line of code                                                                                                        "The constructor DefaultTableModel(Object[]) is undefined"